# What is the proper way of sending an array of WCHAR to winproc as a LPARAM?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dynamic, memory-leaks

So I've got a corruption of the heap problem and wondered if it could have to do with how I work with some arrays. Actually, at some point I have a few messages like this sent to my WinProc:

```
SendMessage(hwnd, LOG_ADD, NULL, (LPARAM)L"Initializing winsock... ");
```

LOG_ADD is defined as 104. Inside WinProc, when msg==LOG_ADD, the following happens:

```
case LOG_ADD:
            {
                pGame->pMessageLog->PutToLog((WCHAR*)lParam);
                pGame->pD2DResources->OnRender(pGame->pMessageLog);
```

There is MessageLog::PutToLog(WCHAR[]):

```
void MessageLog::PutToLog(WCHAR txt[])
{
    int strLen=wcslen(txt);
    int logLen=wcslen(logHistory);

    WCHAR* pWCHAR = txt;

    int x=0;

    // Counts the number of '\n' into wString and adds that number to nLogLines
    for(x=0; x<strLen; x++)
    {
        if(pWCHAR[x]=='\n')
            nLogLines++;
    }

    pWCHAR = logHistory;

    x=0;
    while(nLogLines>5)
    {
        if(pWCHAR[x]=='\n')
            nLogLines--;
        x++;
    }

    if(x!=0)
    {
        for(int y=0; y<logLen-x; y++)
        {
            pWCHAR[y]=pWCHAR[y+x];
        }
    }

    wcscat (logHistory, txt);
}
```

Could this explain the corruption problem? Actually, when I remove all the SendMessage(hwnd, LOG_ADD...) lines, the corruption doesn't appear a few lines later when the compiler executes the line "struct hostent* host;" or "if((host=gethostbyname(server))==NULL)".

Comment: How do you know you have heap corruption?

Comment: My program breaks and I get this message. However, I just realised I didn't initialize nLogLines and logHistory. Now that I initialize them, the corruption of the heap problem is gone, although I still have other problems.

Still, is this the proper way of sending a WCHAR array as a LPARAM and sending it to another function to use?

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron - yes what you are doing is fine.  That is exactly what `WM_SETTEXT` does.

Comment: Does that actually decay the array and then convert the pointer, or just try to fit the array?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. If I do, I'd say it only fit the array to a maximum of 5 lines.

Comment: `PutToLog` looks very suspicious to me. In addition to it looking inefficient (every `wcscat` traverses the source string) and hard to read, I don't see any bounds checking.

Comment: I see a probable problem - you are passing a const wchar_t* from SendMessage and freely treating it as wchar_t* and then assigning to it the statement pWCHAR[y] = pWCHAR[y+x]. The program would crash because hardcoded string are stored only in readonly memory pages.

Comment: PutToLog isn't over yet. I first wanted to know if the text would print on the screen. I know it will also crash when logHistory becomes larger than its max size - I still have no protection for that.

Thank you for pointing that though @asveikau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked in a comment:

> is this the proper way of sending a WCHAR array as a LPARAM and sending it to another function to use?

Sure, as long as you know what you pass at the call site and make sure you treat it (cast it) as the type it actually is in the window procedure, this is perfectly fine.

Just make sure you're properly handling any pointers to memory that might be invalid at the time you access it. For instance if you **post** a message instead of **sending** it and pass a pointer to memory that runs out of scope before the receiver handles the message.

Also remember to properly initialize any data you send...